# Search for terms in list within dataframe column, add terms found to new column

Tags: python

**Example dataframe:**

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Nick', 'Matthew', 'Paul'],
                     'Text': ["Lived in Norway, England, Spain and Germany with his car",
                              "Used his bikes in England. Loved his bike",
                              "Lived in Alaska"]})
```

[image]

**Example list:**

```
example_list = ["England", "Bike"]
```

**What I need**

I want to create a new column, called `x`, where if a term from `example_list` is found as a string/substring in `data.Text` (case insensitive), it adds the word it was found from to the new column.

*Output*

[image]

So in row 1, the word England was found and returned, and bike was found and returned, as well as bikes (which bike was a substring of).

**Progress so far:**

I have managed - with the following code - to return terms that match the terms regardless of case, however it wont find substrings... e.g. if search for "bike", and it finds "bikes", I want it to return "bikes".

```
pattern = fr'({"|".join(example_list)})'
data['Text'] = data['Text'].str.findall(pattern, flags=re.IGNORECASE).str.join(", ")
```

Comment: "extractall" takes "flags" like Python's regex functions to enable case-insensitive match. To match in a word you can replace `r'({})'` e. g. by `r'(\S*(?:{})\S*)'` (may need fine tuning).

Comment: Looking now, ty Michael!

Comment: That particular regex does not work, but I will try and edit it (not too good with regex!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I might have found a solution for your pattern there:

```
pattern = fr'({"|".join("[a-zA-Z]*" + ex + "[a-zA-Z]*" for ex in example_list)})'
data['x'] = data['Text'].str.findall(pattern, flags=re.IGNORECASE).str.join(",")
```

Basically what I do is, I extend the pattern by optionally allowing letters before the (I think you don't explicitly mention this, maybe this has to be omitted) and after the word.

As an output I get the following:

[image]

I'm just not so sure, in which format you want this x-column. In your code you join it via commas (which I followed here) but in the picture you only have a list of the values. If you specify this, I could update my solution.

Comment: Hi, I actually just solved it as well (a second fresh view helped!) with "pattern = fr'\b[a-zA-Z]*?(?:{"|".join(qexample_list)})[a-zA-Z]*\b'"... ensuring there is no spaces in my list. But yes, yours works perfectly, and I will award the bounty to you! :)... ty very much!!

Comment: Oh, I have to wait 22 hours to award your bounty, but will do so. Ty again :)